# Script removal of Insider Hub app-Win10

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-10

I'd like to script the removal of the Windows 10 Insider Hub app. I've had no success with Powershell-admin: `get-appxpackage -allusers -name *insider* | remove-appxpackage`

I can do it manually in the GUI, but its not automated. [There is a 3rd-party EXE that'll remove it](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1843), but I'd prefer not to use that (on top of the fact I tested it in a VM & the process froze)

**Be aware: I'm using the free Win10 Pro upgrade, so I can't go Enterprise LTSB (which I understand can solve alot of this) & consequently can't DISM the WIM file.**

Bonus points: how-to remove 'Contact Support' & 'Windows Feedback' script`omatically

Comment: Removal of all the windows store app a issue?

Comment: No? I used the script below to remove most apps & it works wonders, but it didn't get rid of the "Insider Hub" app, I can uninstall manually, but would like to do it via a powershell script: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mniehaus/2015/11/11/removing-windows-10-in-box-apps-during-a-task-sequence/

Comment: I asked as I was writting an answer, but it was hitting the store, thus I asked before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested the below on a PC successfully:

```
dism.exe /online /Remove-Package /PackageName:Microsoft-Windows-InsiderHub-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.10586.0
```

I got the packagename from the [DISM cmd switch `get-packages`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825265.aspx):

```
dism /online /get-packages > getpackages.txt
```